# What does "crimen de la parrilla" mean?

Tags: modismos

This appears to translate as "crime of the grill" but apparently it is some kind of idiom unrelated to the [parrilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrilla_(torture)) torture device. Could you explain it? I've also seen it as "crimen en una parrilla", e.g.,

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nijMLCgWSQs
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0-l-3iUwBY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCavNr8dlyw
- > Fue conocido como el crimen de la Parrilla.
- > El 18 de junio de 1883 el tribunal de Jerez condenó a muerte por **el crimen de la Parrilla** a siete personas y a otras ocho, entre ellas al delator de sus compañeros, a diecisiete años y cuatro meses de prisión.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not mean anything: "La Parrilla" was just the name of the ranch where the third of a [series of murders](https://www.diariobahiadecadiz.com/version1_0/noticias/reportajemanonegra1.htm) happened in 1882:

> El último de los casos es el recordado como el ‘Crimen de la Parrilla’, por ser en un cortijo llamado así donde supuestamente se perpetró el asesinato, consumado el 4 de diciembre de 1882, de Bartolomé Gago Campos, conocido como ‘Blanco de Benaocaz’.

Notice that "Parrilla" here is written with a capital letter just like in your quote. That means it is a proper name. Like saying "the Boston murders".

Answer (score 1):

*Supplementary answer.*

You also asked about "crimen en una parrilla."  I googled this as an exact phrase.  Here's  an [example hit](https://tn.com.ar/policiales/crimen-en-una-parrilla-en-avellaneda-una-moza-apunalo-a-un-hombre_501555):

> todo comenzó cuando la empleada de la parrilla comenzó a discutir con el hombre

From the context it's clear that "parrilla" here is a certain kind of restaurant.  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/parrilla) translates it as

**grillroom, steak restaurant**